# how to use smtp server for sending email in java with dynamic from address email id?

Tags: java, smtp

I am using the following code for sending email:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,    MessagingException
{
    SendMail javaEmail = new SendMail();
    javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
    javaEmail.draftEmailMessage();
    javaEmail.sendEmail();
}

private void setMailServerProperties()
{
    Properties emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "586");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
}

private MimeMessage draftEmailMessage() throws AddressException, MessagingException
{
    String[] toEmails = { "aa@gmail.com" };
    String emailSubject = "Test email subject";
    String emailBody = "This is an email sent by http://www.howtodoinjava.com.";
    MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    /**
     * Set the mail recipients
     * */
    for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++)
    {
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
    }
    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    /**
     * If sending HTML mail
     * */
    emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
    /**
     * If sending only text mail
     * */
    //emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email
    return emailMessage;
}

private void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException
{
    /**
     * Sender's credentials
     * */
    String fromUser = "user-email@gmail.com";
    String fromUserEmailPassword = "*******";

    String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
    /**
     * Draft the message
     * */
    MimeMessage emailMessage = draftEmailMessage();
    /**
     * Send the mail
     * */
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");
}
```

}

and I added java mail jar files to project.In this line `transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);`  I have to set the password.

But what I want is sending an email with from address is dynamic. That means user can set their email address and they sends email from the user entered email id to some email id.

Comment: Really looking forward your suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set both from address and sender address on the `MimeMessage`. They don't have to be the same. In your `draftEmailMessage` method, add something like:

```
emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress, fromName));
emailMessage.setSender(new InternetAddress(senderEmailAddress, senderName));
```

Here, `fromEmailAddress` & `fromName` is address and name that the user enters (name is optional).

Correspondingly the `senderEmailAdress` and `senderName` is the address and name of the sender.